# Poner un elemento por encima de otro en html con css

Tags: html5, css3, cakephp, div

tengo dos atributos en el html, pero me queda uno por encima del otro y quiero que el que me quede por encima es el otro.

ya les muestro la foto

Así debe quedar [image: Objetivo]

Así va [image: Actual]

Codigo

Default.ctp (Menu)

```
<div class="menuPrincipal">
                    <div class="">
                        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>                  
                        <div class="menuContenido">
                            <a href="#" class="separador"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="separador"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="separador"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuHome separador lang" key="linkHome">Laboratorio estratégico</a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuNeeds separador lang" key="linkNeeds">Descubrir necesidades</a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuStrategies separador lang" key="linkStrategies">Definir estrategias</a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuTools separador lang" key="linkTools">Herramientas</a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuExecution separador lang" key="linkExecution">Ejecución</a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuResults separador lang" key="linkResults">Resultados</a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuExplore separador lang" key="linkExplore">Explora resultados</a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuTeam separador lang" key="linkTeam">Equipo Seadog</a>
                            <a href="#" class="linkMenuContact separador lang" key="linkContact">Contáctenos</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Default.ctp(wizard/circulos)

```
<div class="circle" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="linkBrowserHome activado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserNeeds desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserStrategies desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserTools desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserExecution desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserResults desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

myStyle.css(menu)

```
.separador{
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.menuOpciones{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 870px;
    width: 700px;
    opacity: 0.96;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*margin-left: 890px;*/
    margin-left: 600px;
    position: absolute;
}
.menuContenido {
    /*display: none;*/
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #E42090;
    min-width: 160px;
    /*box-shadow: -20px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
    top: -100px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 923px;
    opacity: 0.96;
}
.menuContenido a {
    color: #f5BDD6;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.menuPrincipal{
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;  

}
.menuContenido a:hover {
    /*background-color: greenyellow*/
    color: #fffeff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menuPrincipal:hover .menuContenido {
    display: block;
}
.menuPrincipal:hover .dropbtn {
    /*background-color: brown;*/
}
```

myStyle.css(wizard/circulos)

```
.circle {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    right: 60%;
    z-index: 200;
}
.circle ul{
    list-style: none;
    cursor:pointer; 
    cursor: hand;
    display: inline-block;

}
.circle ul li {
    float: none;
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    z-index: 10;
    border: solid 1px #B7B7B7;
    left: 50%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.desactivado:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);transform:scale(1.3);
}

.activado{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0em 13px #EA0B8C;
}
```

PD: como hago para publicar con ejecución online? he visto que algunas personas lo hacen

uso boootstrap 4, cakephp 2 y no se que version de js

Comment: El z-index puede ayudarte https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp :))

Comment: El z-index puede ayudarte https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp :))

Comment: como dijo un compañero arriba... "z-index" esta la solución, [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMhpX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMhpX.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.circle ul li {
float: none;
content: '';
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #FEFEFE;
margin: 20px 30px;
z-index: -2;
border: solid 1px #B7B7B7;
left: 50%;
box-sizing: content-box;
```

}

/*EL z-index deberas configurarlo para colocarlo detras */

Comment: Funciona, pero ya el evento click en los círculos deja de funcionar

Answer (score 1):

```
Subiendo el z-index del contenedor se resuelve el problema posiblemente

.menuContenido {
/*display: none;*/
position: absolute;
background-color: #E42090;
min-width: 160px;
/*box-shadow: -20px 1px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
z-index: 999; /*Subiendo el z-index del contenedor resuelves ese problema*/
left: 50%;
top: -100px;
width: 960px;
height: 923px;
opacity: 0.96;
```

}